# on select radio, redirect to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, onselect

I have three radios and i want onselect of anyone to be redirected to a link. Using javascript or jquery

```
    All <input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="" checked="checked"/>&nbsp;
    Events<input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="Events" />&nbsp;Classes<input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="Classes"/><br /><br />
```

so since "All" is default checked, i want it to go to mysite.com/search.aspx.
now if user selects Events, I want to redirect user to mysite.com/search?type=Events
or if user selects Classes, I want to redirect the user to mysite.com/search?type=Classes
 as response to the onselect of the radios. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just make them `<a>` tags instead of radio buttons?  Users don't expect radio buttons to cause a page reload.

Comment: I agree with Pointy. What you want can be achieved, but I'm not sure that's how you should be handling this sitaution.

Comment: A better option would be to pull the radio value, perform the search, then display results in the page you want to redirect to. If the radio buttons cause a page load, the user would need to wait for the page load to complete before finishing the search, or re-input search parameters unless you're going to pass them to the new page. That seems annoying to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
All     <input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="" checked="checked" onclick ="goToLocation(this.value)"/>&nbsp;
Events  <input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="Events" onclick ="goToLocation(this.value)"/>&nbsp;
Classes <input name="EventRadio" type="radio" value="Classes" onclick ="goToLocation(this.value)"/><br /><br />


function goToLocation(val){
 if(val == "Events")
     window.location = "go to Events location";
 if(val == "Classes")
     window.location = "go to Classes location";
window.location = "go to default location";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a demonstration:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    radios = [],
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    url = 'mysite.com/search?type=';

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i<len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == 'radio'){
        radios.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}

for (var r=0, leng = radios.length; r<leng; r++){
    radios[r].onchange = function(){
        if (this.value){
            /* in real life use:
            document.location = url + this.value;
            */
            output.innerHTML = url + this.value;
        }
        else {
            /* in real life use:
            document.location = 'mysite.com/search?type=Events';
            */
            output.innerHTML = 'mysite.com/search.aspx';
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nbuz6/).

Please note that I've also changed your mark up to use `<label>` elements, and removed the `&nbsp;`s and `<br />`s.

Comment: Thank you. Now instead of outputting it, can we store that as the value of current URL?  If we can then it would solve my issue because basically i am trying to grab the query string value and pass to the XSL as parameter!!?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val !== ''){
        window.location = 'http://mysite.com/search?type=' + val;
    }else{
        window.location = 'http://mysite.com/search.aspx';
    }
});
```